# How to solve this seeming "paradox" of time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I was sitting in the balcony one day and this question popped up in my head.

Suppose there are two inertial frames $S$ and $S'$ such that $S'$ is moving with some velocity $v$ with respect to $S$ along their common x-axis.

Now imagine a system of two objects (both moving with velocity $v$ along the common x-axis too) initially separated far from each other such that the rest mass of both is $m_o$ as seen from $S'$. If the system is left alone the masses will collide due to gravity .

[image]

From the frame of $S'$, acceleration of each mass will be :-

$$a'= \frac{Gm_o}{r^2}$$

While for the observer in $S$ the acceleration of each mass will be :-

$$a=\frac{\gamma Gm_o}{r^2}$$

From the above equations , it is clear that the acceleration in the $S$ frame is more than that in $S'$ frame. And since the total distance covered before collision is same for both the observers this means that when the collision happens the clock in $S$ should read lesser time than the clock in $S'$ which were synchronised to t=0 just before the masses started to move.

Now this is in complete contradiction to what lorentz transformations suggest. *The time in moving frame should slow down but here the time in the moving frame is faster than that of the rest frame*.

**How to solve this seeming "paradox" ?**

There must be something wrong with the setup I have created that is leading to this result. But where exactly ?

Comment: Why are you using Newtonian gravity, which is a non-relativistic force? You should use either general relativity or classical electromagnetism.

Comment: 1. From what you've written it is not clear how you've arrived at the different acceleration in frame $S$. 2. Why are you trying to use Newtonian gravity inside of special relativity? The correct way of combining special relativity and gravity is *general relativity*.

Comment: In S' the masses move at right angles to the x axis, but in S they follow an angled path, so try to work out the implications of that.

Comment: @Dale actually i am just having an introductory course in Special relativity adn have no course on general theory yet. So I apologise for this stupid question. But can you explain it intuitively how the general relativity will fix this problem ?

Comment: No, the equations of general relativity are not intuitive at all. If you want intuition then I would recommend using electromagnetism instead. Classical electromagnetism is fully relativistic, so it works with such questions. Provided you already have some intuition on how EM works

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to put the masses at rest in $S$, at

$$E_{(0, \pm)} = (t, x_{\pm})=(0, \pm L)$$

because that is simpler. They are free to move after $t=0$ and collide at:

$$E_1 = (T, 0)$$

In $S'$, which shares an origin with $S$, you get:

$$  E'_1 = (\gamma T,-\gamma vT) $$

The problem is when do they start moving:

$$E'_{(0, \pm)} = (\mp\gamma  vL, \pm\gamma L)$$

So in $S'$, the masses start moving at different times. That complicated the comparison.

Willy nilly multiplying by $\gamma$ without considering the coordinates of events and lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

A meta-answer.

Whenever you're dealing with special relativity, it is important to note that everything is subject to change, except the speed of light. When considering two different frames of reference - the events might no longer be simultaneous, the distances between objects might no longer be the same, their velocity/acceleration might be different, electromagneticforces might change their nature, etc. One of these generally explains the apparent anomaly.